# How to make program return Console.Writeline("ERROR INVALID INPUT") rather than give me an exception?

Tags: c#, exception

In my code:

```
{
    int coffecost = 0;
    string coffesize = null;
    Console.WriteLine("1. Small 2. Medium 3. Large");
    Console.WriteLine("Choose your coffe please but enter your name first!");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("So your name is {0}! What coffe would you like?", name);
    int coffetype = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (coffetype)
    {
        case 1:
            coffecost += 1;
            coffesize = "small";
            break;
        case 2:
            coffecost += 2;
            coffesize = "medium";
            break;
        case 3:
            coffecost += 3;
            coffesize = "Large";
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is an invalid choice please choose from one of the 3!", coffetype); 
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Receipt: \n Name: {0} \n Coffee type: {1} \n Coffee cost: {2} \n Coffee size: {3}", name, coffetype, coffecost, coffesize);
}
```

This simple program generates a receipt from the type of coffee. Now in my program you put 1, 2, or 3 to indicate small, medium, large. However if you input an invalid character say "," then you'll receive an exception and the program will crash. I want to have the program return "This is not a type of coffee!" Rather than crash how could I do this. Also for practice I plan to add a feature where you can add ingredients such as cream, sugar, or artificial sweetener and other items. Now I want to be able to put all these ingredients in on the same line and have it read them out. For example I put in cream, sugar, artificial sweetener and it says you put in (and it reads out the ingredients) But if I don't put in say sugar I want it to just print "You chose cream and artificial sweetener! All help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the

```
int coffetype = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

to

```
int coffetype = 0;

if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out coffetype)) {
    Console.Writeline(“ERROR INVALID INPUT”);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining me the purpose of the ! that is right before int.tryparse?

Comment: Sure @MattJones, ! is a negation operator of boolean expression, if you look at the TryParse signature at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you will see that this method returns True if it can parse provided string and false otherwise, so in this case we need write "Error Invalid Input" only if TryParse failed to parse string value

Comment: so basically it makes it so that way I don't have to put bool = int.tryparse(Input, out output);

Answer (score 0):

You use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int coffetype;
string input  = Console.ReadLine();
if(!Int32.TryParse(input, out coffetype))
   Console.WriteLine(coffeType.ToString() + " IS AN INVALID INPUT");
else
{
   .....
}
```

This method tries to convert the input string in an integer, but, in case of errors, it doesn't throw an exception and simply return false leaving the variable `coffetype` to its default value of 0.

In your context you could also avoid the test and let the default case in the switch handle the invalid input.

```
int coffetype;
string input  = Console.ReadLine();

// Not really need to test if Int32.TryParse return false,
// The default case in the following switch will handle the
// default value for coffetype (that's zero)
Int32.TryParse(input, out coffetype);
switch (coffetype)
{
    case 1:
       .....
    default:
       Console.WriteLine("{0} is an invalid choice please choose from one of the 3!", coffetype);
       break;
}
```